# Python - Total number of permutation of a string

Tags: python, count, permutation

I had to program a method that printed all permutations of a string and how many there were.

```
def generate_anagrams(s):
  global np # variable to count the number of anagrams generated.
  a = list(s)
  np=0
  permutations(a,0)
  print("There are", np, "anagrams")

def permutations(a,i=0): # generate all permutations of a[i:]
  global np
  
  if i == len(a):
    print(''.join(a))
  for j in range(i, len(a)):
    copyString = [k for k in a]
    copyString[i], copyString[j] = copyString[j], copyString[i]
    permutations(copyString,i+1)
    np += 1
```

So when I do: `genera_anagramas("ab")` the output should be:

```
ab
ba 
There are 2 anagrams.
```

However, the count is returning :

```
ab
ba
There are 4 anagrams
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You recursively call `permutations` in your code, so it will be modifying `np` as well.

Comment: Neither 'ab' nor 'ba' is an anagram

Answer (score 0):

Like someone wrote in the comments, it's better to return the variable `np` rather than use it as global.
Anyway python has an internal function in `itertools` package to compute string permutation. Example:

```py
from itertools import permutations

words = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('exa')]

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['exa', 'eax', 'xea', 'xae', 'aex', 'axe']
```